# Using a jQuery Plugin ddSlick Dropdown - How do I dynamically populate JSON data?

Tags: jquery

I have what is likely a pretty simple question.  I have a jQuery plugin for a fancy dropdown box.

The plugin is called with:

```
$('#demoBasic').ddslick({
    data: ddData,
    width: 300,
    imagePosition: "left",
    selectText: "Select your favorite social network",
    onSelected: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The JSON data to populate the dropdown is:

```
var ddData = [
{
    text: "Facebook",
    value: 1,
    selected: false,
    description: "Description with Facebook",
    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
},
{
    text: "Twitter",
    value: 2,
    selected: false,
    description: "Description with Twitter",
    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
}
];
```

So what I want to do is populate that JSON data dynmically.   I can write the PHP code to do my search and return the JSON, but how would I do that programmtically so it would load it based on a search?

I had an idea of just loading it up through an ajax post but and then returning the result in a div.... would that work?

Like:

```
submitHandler: function() {
    $.post('lookup.php', $("#lookup").serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    });
},
```

Can I return a jQuery script thorugh that type of call?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue yesterday where I wanted to update the ddSlick options when another filter is changed. The simplest approach I found for that was to destroy and rebuild.

In this example I'm filtering a list of options, but the approach would apply to options provided by an Ajax call or however else. Whenever the `image_folder_select` selection is changed:

1. a new list of options is generated. In this example, I'm using jQuery's `grep` to create a new filtered array by matching items in `ddData` by an extra custom property (`image_folder_id`). Note: the master `ddData` list is defined when the page is loaded.
2. the `image_select` select list is restored to it's original state via `ddslick('destroy')`.
3. a new ddSlick instance, with the new list of options, is bound to the `image_select`.

Example:

```
$("#image_folder_select").change(function () {
    filtered_ddData = $.grep(ddData, function(e) {return e.image_folder_id == $("#image_folder_select").val()});

    $('#image_select').ddslick('destroy');
    $('#image_select').ddslick({
        data: filtered_ddData,
        width: 512,
        height: 256,
        onSelected: function(data){
            $('#image_file_id').val(data.selectedData.value);
        }
    });
});
```